# Filling a data frame with synthetic data

Tags: python, faker, synthetic

I am trying to fill and save a DataFrame with fake data from the Faker package but I am struggling to return more that one row of data.

I tried using a for loop but it didn't quite work. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

```
from faker import Faker
import pandas as pd

fake = Faker()

def create_df(range):
    
    data={'Name':[fake.name()],'address':[fake.address()],"email":[fake.email()] }
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)

    return df

df
```

Thanks.

Comment: just use list comprehension in each of the data values... `[fake.name() for i in range(200)]` and the same for address and email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this modified code:

```
from faker import Faker
import pandas as pd

fake = Faker()

def create_df(rows_count):

    data=[{'Name':fake.name(),'address':fake.address(),"email":fake.email() } for x in range(rows_count)]
    df=pd.DataFrame(data)

    return df
```

*rows_count*, as the name suggest serves to select the number of rows you want your dataset to have.

Hope it helps.